# How to rotate touchpad

Tags: manjaro, touchpad, libinput

I am sometimes using the apple magic trackpad and would find it more convenient, if I could use it upside down. Thus I was looking  for a way to rotate my input. I stumpled upon libinput and some rotation option mentioned here https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/configuration.html

However I could not find any example on how to enable that option. How do I proceed?

```
$ lininput list-devices
Device:           Apple Wireless Trackpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event29
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             132x112mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    button-areas *clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

Comment: Might be that with `xinput`, though I'm not sure. Please show what options are available for your trackpad with `xinput` *(execute `xinput list` to list devices, and the `xinput list-props "Device name"`, where the "Device name" is one from the `xinput list` output)*.

Comment: `xinput list` only gives me one `virtual core xtest pointer` and some `xwayland pointer, xwayland relative pointer`. However I dont which one my Apple Trackpad is

Comment: Ah, okay, so you're on wayland. This is an important point, in this case `xinput` would be of no help, the configuration is handled solely by your compositor. That is, your question become compositor-specific. If you're using Gnome, I think you could try an option "natural scrolling" in settings *(I'm not sure whether it does what you want though)*. If your compositor does not have a way to exploit that libinput feature, you may have to create a feature request. But it is worth noting, that for Gnome for example, not everything has GUI to it, a few things may only be edited with `gsettings`.